# Google Maps: how to disable automatic street view?

Tags: google-maps

When you scroll upwards in Google Maps, at some point the map would enter horizontal Street View mode.

How can this behavior be stopped? I'd like to be able to zoom in "all the way" without it defaulting into Street View mode.

Answer (score 3):

I just tried the solution suggested by Raghu Ranganathan, but that doesn't seem to work anymore.
There's no '&z=' part in the url anymore, so it seems.

Luckily I found another way to change the zoom level.

The url contains the longitude and latitude coordinates after the @-sign, followed by a distance in meters determining the zoom level.
You can change this value in the url to change the zoom level.

Examples:

- [Zoom level 200m](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Verstoppertjebrug,+Almere,+Netherlands/@52.3765352,5.1981877,200m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x47c61729b68ffb07:0x2c3f4cf3921bca80!8m2!3d52.3765805!4d5.1989785?hl=en)
- [Zoom level 10m](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Verstoppertjebrug,+Almere,+Netherlands/@52.3765352,5.1981877,10m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x47c61729b68ffb07:0x2c3f4cf3921bca80!8m2!3d52.3765805!4d5.1989785?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to remove that feature from Google Maps, since Google has permanently made it so.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/26NPPxYduKc

It is not possible to modify the behaviour of the zoom feature within google maps itself. I've not found any extension which can disable this feature as well

If you want to zoom in a bit further than Google Maps allows, you can take the link of your location, example: [This Place](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Verstoppertjebrug,+Almere,+Netherlands/@52.3765352,5.1981877,38m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x47c61729b68ffb07:0x2c3f4cf3921bca80!8m2!3d52.3765805!4d5.1989785?hl=en) , go to the end of the URL  and change the &z= attribute to a higher number.(>23 in this case)

Comment: Is there a url segment that I can type in directly to get the "max zoom" of a page?

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how to get beyond the max zoom of a page. However, it works only when Google has a high-res image of the location you are zooming into. https://lifehacker.com/the-hidden-way-to-zoom-in-closer-in-google-maps-476437355